nemo menu right click wipe add confirm message
[Nemo Action]
Name=wipe file
Name[en]=wipe file
Comment[en]=wipe file
Exec=/usr/bin/wipe -rf %F 
Icon-Name=gtk-dialog-warning
Selection=S
Extensions=any;
Quote=double

I added the action to nemo. Right clicking a file displays a wipe file option in the menu. And
clicking wipe file deletes the file. I do not know how to verify if it wipes it correctly.
How do you get nemo to display a confirm wiping message when you click the nemo wipe file option? As
it is, if you by mistake click wipe file the file in question gets wiped. When it says Exec=/usr/bin/wipe -rf %F the f makes wipe discard displaying a confirm message. By editing the nemo action file I tested command Exec=/usr/bin/wipe -r %F. No confirm wipe message displays and the file does not get wiped. Thanks.
I cannot get the add comment to work. The following is what I wanted to add in a comment.
when you in the nemo menu right click wipe file I want a confirm wiping message to display. The question is how do you alter the action code in order to achieve that?

What is the question?
